# Check if drive has enough space before writing

Tags: backup, unix, unix-shell

I am looking to make a backup to a remote drive, but I want to do a check prior to doing so.

Is it possible to snatch only the "Available" space from the `df` output, rather than all of the details, to compare to the size of the dump?

Comment: do you have ssh access ot the remote drive's host machine ? I assume yes

Comment: try: df  | grep -i <mount point> | awk '{print $3}'

Answer (score 3):

Sirex,

I had to change it to `$print 4`, but that is exactly what was needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can void the use of grep by running `df <mountpoint>`.  Note also that this will fail for long device names, because `df` will then use two lines of output for the filesystem, which will throw off your column count.  You can avoid this -- under Linux -- by running `df -P <mountpoint>`, which ensures a single line of output per filesystem.